# How to implement push notifications if a website doesn't natively support them?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, retrofit

There is a very simple website I would like to make an app for. Unfortunately it doesn't have any official API. However, it does have an option to export certain data in json. For instance, messages.

If I wanted to push new messages to a user, what would be best practice on android?

Do I just have to do a background refresh of the message page, using retrofit, every 5 minutes or so? Intuitively this seems like it would waste a lot of battery, but I can't think of a better way to implement such a feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best answer, but have you tried the Firebase push notifications?

Give it a try, really good solution to implement push notifications up and downstream, to multiple devices or single device and supporting multiple protocols too, here you have some links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device

Send me PM if you need some help to start, but i think the documentation is really good on the website.

Comment: Thanks for posting about firebase, I'm actually very interested in using it. But, would firebase be able to facilitate logging into a third party website?

Comment: yeah, no  problem you can write your code in the middle acting like an intermediary

Comment: Where would I write that the code that say checks for new messages from the website. Would that also be on firebase notifications?

Comment: Firebase notifications allow you to have push notifications, you can write any code you want to retrieve the information you need. 
You can send push notifications from their website too, but i think what you want is to do that programmatically. And yes that is completely possible, just check the documentation. Hope i answered your question.